# Three concurrent line segments

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Can you provide a proof for the following claim:

> **Claim.** Given an arbitrary $\triangle ABC$. The  $\triangle ADB$ , $\triangle BEC$ and $\triangle CFA$ are constructed on the sides of the  $\triangle ABC$ externally , such that $\angle BAD=\angle ECB$ , $\angle DBA=\angle ACF$ and $\angle CBE=\angle FAC$ . Let $H_1$,$H_2$,$H_3$ be the orthocenters of the $\triangle ADB$ , $\triangle BEC$, $\triangle CFA$, respectively. Then the line segments $AH_2$, $BH_3$ and $CH_1$ concur at the point $P$.

[image]

GeoGebra applet that demonstrates this problem can be found [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/u8yq86pf).

My idea is to apply [Jacobi's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_theorem_(geometry)#:%7E:text=In%20plane%20geometry%2C%20a%20Jacobi,YCA%20%3D%20%E2%88%A0XCB%20%3D%20%CE%B3.) on this problem. In order to do that we need to prove the following identities $\angle BAH_1=\angle H_3AC$, $\angle H_1BA=\angle CBH_2$ and $\angle H_2CB=\angle ACH_3$ but I don't know how this can be done. Any hints are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Clearly in $\triangle BDC$, $\angle HBE$ is complementary to $\angle ACB$.

Hence in the OP's diagram, $\angle H_3AC = 90 - \angle ACF = 90 - \angle DBA = \angle BAH_1$.

Same for others.